# If filtering same data twice, why does Array.filter takes almost 10 times more time than $filter if executed at once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, google-chrome, filter

***I am trying to compare the time taken by angular's $filter service and Array.filter method of javascript.***

**This issue is reproducible in chrome only.**

If I run both methods simultaneously then every time one filter takes almost 10 times more time to filter array in comparison to other filter but if I run them separately then both of them take almost equal time.

**Using Array.filter method :-**

```
arr.filter(function(a){
    return ((a.buyout - 33333333) === 0);
});
```

**Using $filter :-**

```
$filter('filter')(resp.alliance.auctions, function(data){
      return ((data.buyout - 33333333) === 0);
});
```

*Is here any caching issue(or feature) with filter?*

plnkr with working code:- http://plnkr.co/edit/A5UeZK6Jnafp9SkVBxZi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code optimisation will play a role here. The variant of your code that will come to execute first, will access the returned structure for the first time. Chrome might have saved some resources before that first access actually happens, but once you *do* make that access, Chrome has to make that data accessible on the fly.

When you change the order of actual execution, for instance by wrapping the `Array#filter` block in a `setTimeout`, you will notice that then the `$filter` method consumes more time, and the `Array#filter` one wins. So really, the one that executes first has more overhead going on than the second.

For a correct comparison, you'd have to first access the input array and `$filter` without measuring time, and only then execute the two variants, so they start as much as possible in the same situation.

With the following arrangement, the difference in time consumption is very small:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($filter, $http, $scope){
  $http.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://auction-api-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/auction-data/258993a3c6b974ef3e6f22ea6f822720/auctions.json').success(function(resp){
    // Perform a dry run to make sure all resources are loaded:
    var result = resp.alliance.auctions.filter(function(a){
      return ((a.buyout - 33333333) === 0);
    });
    result = $filter('filter')(resp.alliance.auctions, function(a){
      return ((a.buyout - 33333333) === 0);
    });
    var start = performance.now(), diffArrayFilter = 0, diff$filter = 0;

    // Now start the real measurement
    start = performance.now();
    result = $filter('filter')(resp.alliance.auctions, function(a){
      return ((a.buyout - 33333333) === 0);
    });
    diff$filter = performance.now() - start;

    start = performance.now();
    result = resp.alliance.auctions.filter(function(a){
      return ((a.buyout - 33333333) === 0);
    });
    diffArrayFilter = performance.now() - start;

    $scope.time = 'Time taken by $filter: '+diff$filter.toFixed(2)+' ms';

    document.getElementById('aLength').innerHTML = 'Array Length: '+resp.alliance.auctions.length;
    document.getElementById('fTime').innerHTML = 'Time taken by Array.filter: '+diffArrayFilter.toFixed(2)+' ms';
    document.getElementById('fLength').innerHTML = 'Filtered Array Length: '+result.length;
  });
});
```

See your [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kJcKP4qPposTGxenCcNx?p=preview)

Comment: But why this happens in chrome only? I tried my same code on firefox and IE but they gave me almost same(and very less) execution time.

Comment: So, does it means I will have to execute my same code before measuring actual performance? Isn't there any other optimized way?

Comment: Browser implementations differ, they are free to do so. In some scenarios one will be outperform the other, while in another situation it will be the opposite. The internal mechanics have evolved a lot, with focus on improving performance on code patterns that are common. If you want to measure code without an interest in the initial overhead it might have to deal with, then yes, you need to get that overhead out of the way.

Comment: Of course, if you want to measure the difference and take such overhead cost as part of the measurement, you would execute the code once with one method, and again from scratch (new page load) with the other.